# How to invoke Gnome 3 activity screen via mouse button?

Tags: linux, command-line, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome3, xbindkeys

#### What I'm trying to do

I'm using a Logitech MX Revolution mouse, which has a button below the scroll wheel mapped to search, which I remapped to middle click. For doing so, I had to remap <kbd>XF86Search</kbd> to middle click using `xbindkeys`, which works fine – when I change the "Search" hotkey to something else, for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>XF86Search</kbd> in the Gnome Settings.

Now I want another mouse button to invoke the Gnome Activity screen (the one with the overview of open windows). <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> also opens this view (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>XF86Search</kbd> now would do it, and even just pressing the super key).

#### Invoking the Gnome Activity screen

I try to send <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> using

```
/usr/bin/xvkbd -text "\[Alt_l]\[F1]"
```

but it seems Gnome 3 does not fetch this key (which is not totally unexpected, as `xvkbd -text` sends it to the focussed window).

What choices do I have do invoke the Gnome Activity screen?

Comment: When you say Activity screen are you referring to the one that comes up when you press the "super" key?

Comment: Yes, either by pressing super or Alt+F1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this AskUbuntu Q&A titled: [Bind a mouse button to show the Gnome Shell Activities overview](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91424/bind-a-mouse-button-to-show-the-gnome-shell-activities-overview). The OP from that Q&A posted that this solution worked for him/her using `xbindkeys`:

```
"xte 'keydown Alt_L' 'key F1' 'keyup Alt_L'"
    release + b:10
```

There were other suggestions in that Q&A as well, so if the accepted answer doesn't work, then perhaps one of the others would suit your needs.

Comment: `xte` did the job and reliably sends the keys to Gnome. Using `xmacroplay` I was able to _sometimes_ invoke the screen, but mostly it didn't work.

Comment: @JensErat - glad that worked out, thanks for the Q!

Comment: Somewhat surprised I didn't find the askubuntu question, I'm pretty sure I ran into another one for a similar problem that didn't work out (using `xvkbd`).

Comment: @JensErat - yeah I saw that one too, I kept digging and found this alternative which seemed to work for me and others.